# Adding ros integrated contact sensors

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone!

I'm building a biped model and I want to add a sensor that detects a collision between its foot and the ground and sends a message to a ROS topic.

The 'Bumper controller' described [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins) sounds pretty much like what I want. But when I try to put the following tag in the .gazebo file:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100</updateRate>
    <bumperTopicName>test_bumper</bumperTopicName>
    <frameName>world</frameName>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

As suggested in the tutorial, I get the following error:

> Error [Model.cc:761] Model[bumper_bot]
> is attempting to load a plugin,  but
> detected an incorrect plugin type.
> Plugin
> filename[libgazebo_ros_bumper.so]
> name[gazebo_ros_bumper_controller]

I ftought it was because I did not specify any link for the sensor, so I tried using:

```
<gazebo reference='base_link'>
```

This time I got the message:

```
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[plugin], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <link>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error [parser.cc:299] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [World.cc:1469] Unable to read sdf string
```

I also tried to follow [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/29158/how-do-i-use-force-sensor-bumper-sensor-in-gazebo/) answer, which suggested using a tag like this:

```
<sensor:contact name="contact_sensor">
  <geom>base_link_geom</geom>
  <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_bumper name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
      <bumperTopicName>bumper</bumperTopicName>
      <interface:bumper name="bumper_iface" />
  </controller:gazebo_ros_bumper>
</sensor:contact>
```

This time the xml couldn't even be parsed.

I did manage to add the gazebo contact sensor

```
<gazebo reference="base_link">
  <sensor type="contact" name="contact">
    <update_rate>100.000000</update_rate>
    <contact>
      <collision>base_link_collision</collision>
      <topic>/contact</topic>
    </contact>
    <plugin name='gazebo_contact' filename='libContactPlugin.so'/>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

But it publishes to a gazebo topic, not a ROS topic.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
I'm using gazebo 1.9.3 and ros-hydro.

P.S: I've noticed the turtlebot has a sensor that does exactly what I want, but I couldn't figure out where to find the plugin which is used there or how to add it to my model.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5355/adding-ros-integrated-contact-sensors/) by [EricSidorov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116/ericsidorov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is an example:

```
<gazebo reference="gripper">
  <sensor name="gripper_contact_sensor" type="contact">
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
    <contact>
      <collision>collision</collision>
    </contact>
    <plugin name="gripper_bumper" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
      <bumperTopicName>gripper_contact_sensor_state</bumperTopicName>
      <frameName>gripper</frameName>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 247 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So did you get it worked? I am trying to do the same but always get an empty topic when using libgazebo_ros_bumper.so and no topic is generated when using my own plugin. How you create collision name using urdf description? Thank you in advance

---

Originally posted by [Gxav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/684/gxav/) with karma: 11 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-06-12**:
I got the same problem, empty topic, though I have tried to work around by following the above link I leave

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-06-12**:
Did you get it done by the way? Thanks!